# How to let an EventSystem raycast through a part of UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm using a modern (Event System) UI approach in Unity. I have a screen space Canvas, some interactable world space elements, and my camera is properly set up with a Physics Raycaster. I want some of my screen space Canvas elements to let rays through and hit the world space elements.

I set the Event Mask on the Physics Raycaster to just the UI layer, and the elements I want to ignore are on another layer, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's a picture:

[image]

The panel itself and the labels on top and bottom are set to the Ignore Raycast layer.

I'm using Unity 2017.4 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set off the raycast target on the UI elements you want to only be visible but no interaction.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-raycastTarget.html

[image: Setting in inspector]